# Can a decision tree learn to solve a xOR problem?

Tags: random-forest, decision-trees

I have read online that decision trees can solve xOR type problems, as shown in images (xOR problem: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01U99.png)) and (Possible solution as decision tree: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQNfk.png)).

My question is how can a decision tree learn to solve this problem in this scenario. I just don't see a way for any metric (Information gain, Gini Score, ...) to choose one of the splits in image 2 over any other random split.

Is it possible to solve the presented problem with a decision tree?
Would using a random forest solve the problem in any way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a decision tree can learn an XOR.

> I have read online that decision trees can solve xOR type problems...

Often things are phrased not carefully enough.  A neural network can perfectly sort a list of integers, but *training* one to do that would be quite hard.  Your image shows that a tree can easily represent the XOR function, but your question is how to *learn* such a tree structure.

> My question is how can a decision tree learn to solve this problem in this scenario. I just don't see a way for any metric (Information gain, Gini Score, ...) to choose one of the splits in image 2 over any other random split.

Indeed, the first split is probably quite random, or due to noise (if you go for $\operatorname{sign}(x\cdot y)$ with continuous $x,y$ instead of the discrete $x,y$ and XOR).  But, as long as your algorithm makes the plunge with one of those first splits, the next splits are obvious and your tree will make them.

> Is it possible to solve the presented problem with a decision tree?

[Here's a notebook](https://github.com/bmreiniger/datascience.stackexchange/blob/master/TreeXOR.ipynb) (github/colab, suggestions welcome) demonstrating that yes, a (sklearn) decision tree can learn $\operatorname{sign}(x\cdot y)$ (perhaps with some errors when points are extremely close to 0); but it also goes on to show some of the difficulties, e.g. when variables other than $x,y$ are available to the tree to split on.  Up-shot: noise variables can wreck that first split I mentioned above, and even useful variables can make the tree lose track of the XOR.

> Would using a random forest solve the problem in any way?

Probably not the basic problem, but it looks like it helps with, e.g., the noise variables above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to implement XOR with decision tree.

the XOR gate:

```
if x == y
  class = 0
else
  class = 1
```

A simple discrete decision tree could therefore be:

```
N1: is x == 1 ? (yes -> N2, no -> N3)
N2: is y == 1 ? (yes -> class=0, no -> class=1)
N3: is y == 1 ? (yes -> class=1, no -> class=0)
```

You can therefore implement XOR with three decision nodes.

This can be applied to continuous values as well. I will demonstrate with the example you provided. In your example, we need to make a decision tree that considers the following:

```
if (x < 0.5 AND y > 0.4) OR (x > 0.5 AND y < 0.4)
  class = 1
else
  class = 2
```

Like the discrete example, this can be solved using three decision nodes:

```
N1: is x > 0.5 ? (yes -> N2, no -> N3)
N2: is y > 0.4 ? (yes -> class=2, no -> class=1)
N3: is y > 0.4 ? (yes -> class=1, no -> class=2)
```

Note that you can choose > or >= to skew classification toward your preferred class when a point falls precisely on the boundary.

I have pasted your example image here for reference:
[image: Your example]